# netbeans 7.4 and phonegap sdk location

Tags: java, html, css, netbeans, cordova

I want to try the new version 3.0 of phonegap. Node.js is installed and I tried

`npm install -g phonegap`

Everything seems to be fine after this step.
I use the development version of netbeans because of the phone gap support.
When creating a HTML5->PhoneGap project netbeans needs the location of the phonegap sdk but it doesn't accept any path I try.

What's the correct path/location of the sdk?

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap?

I'm using Windows 7.

thx 4 help

Comment: same problem with linux :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

right now support in NetBeans is for PhoneGap 2.X. The new 3.0 was released very recently and there is a [issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233214) for supporting it

Update: If you want, you can download nightly build with support for the new Cordova 3.0 from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/netbeans/trunk/nightly/latest)

Answer (score 4):

Installing PhoneGap using Node does not seem to work as Netbeans wants the PhoneGap SDK directory. As a work around, You can download 2.9.X version from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/2.9.0.zip and specify the extracted folder as the SDK location.